# Reading metrics in .csv format into prometheus from S3

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, prometheus

I have several hundred IOT devices uploading performance metrics in .csv format into an s3 bucket. I need to get those metrics into my already existing prometheus/alertmanager monitoring solution. I'm attempting to use an existing exporter called mtail (https://github.com/google/mtail), but for the life of me I can't figure out how to use it to parse a CSV file. The documentation says to use awk language, but the way to set a custom delimeter in awk is with -f, but that's not relevant to mtail programs (or is it?).

If there's a better way to get .csv-formatted metrics from S3 into prometheus I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Given the [program execution](https://github.com/google/mtail/blob/master/docs/Language.md#program-execution), I would say it has very little in common with AWK (the syntax is somewhat similar at first glance). Regarding your question of using another tool it depends on how the data is fed : does it overwrite the files ? does it appends to them ? Are multiple files required to generate a metric ? Do you pay to access the bucket ? ...

Comment: Files are appended. A new file is created once every 2-3 hours. Each device only generates a single file. Files are gzip'ed before being uploaded to S3.

Answer (score 2):

I think VictoriaMetrics might be a good option for You https://docs.victoriametrics.com/?highlight=Import#how-to-import-csv-data

Also You might consider its agent for scraping on iot devices.